# Creating a new model versus Using a boolean Conditional in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a rails app which is basically a todo app which allows the user to choose one of two modes at the beginning. The mode will impact the html output the user will see but the basic backend structure will be the same (lists, tasks, ect). For example, light_mode uses a light color scheme and dark mode uses a dark color_scheme. Would it be better to create a new model for Mode or set Mode as a boolean value (true for mode1, false for mode2) and use different views whether mode is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1

Rather than a boolean attribute. I would make a string attribute named scheme. There would originally be only two entries, light and dark, but this would allow you to more easily add other schemes as time goes on. I would add this directly to the User, rather than add a model and association. Either way would likely involve adding a field to the model, might as well add the one you are using right away. This reduces complexity, lets you assign and retrieve the attributes more efficiently, and allows for easier testing. Your model might look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :scheme,
            presence: true,
            inclusion: {
              in: proc { User.schemes },
              allow_blank: true }

  class << self

    def schemes
      [ 'light', 'dark' ]
    end

  end

end
```

Then, you can even use `User.schemes` to populate a drop-down in the user form.

---

## Step 2

To render, I would consider one of two approaches. I would personally do option 1.

### Option 1

If the structure is to be generally the same, I would simply add the user's desired scheme as a class to the body tag, and do all of the styling with css. This is [quite a bit more flexible than you might imagine](http://www.csszengarden.com/).

### Option 2

If css only is simply not an option, you can gain flexibility by sacrificing DRYness.To do so, simply qualify every filename with the style name, or put it in a directory with the styles name, and refer to it with the render call. For example:

```
/app/views/users/index.html.erb
/app/views/users/dark_index.html.erb
/app/views/users/light_index.html.erb
```

or

```
/app/views/users/index.html.erb
/app/views/users/dark/_index.html.erb
/app/views/users/light/_index.html.erb
```

and then in `/app/views/users/index.html.erb`, have nothing but a call to render the specific partial like `render "#{ current_user.theme }_index"` or whatever.

I would very seriously try doing this all with css, if at all possible, before getting into all of that, though.